# SQL many-to-many relation 3 ways

Tags: mysql, sql, database, many-to-many, relationship

Hej all,

> Let's say I have 4 tables named "user", "office", "product", "event".
>   And another table named "document". A same document can be assigned to
>   one or many users, offices, products and events. So here we need a
>   many-to-many relationship. But I have 3 ways to do that :
>
> -a table named "user_document", another named "office_document", "product_document" and "event_document" which all have a field named
>   "document_id" which is foreign key for document id and another field
>   "user_id" (for user_document) which is foreign key to user id (and so
>   on with office, product and event of course...)
>
> OR
>
> -a table named "document_ownership" which has these fields : "document_id", "user_id", "office_id", "product_id" and "event_id".
>   Here document_id should be not Null and one (or more) of other fields
>   that can be Null. For example if I set a same document for a user and
>   a product, I will have a row with document_id, user_id and product_id
>   not Null.
>
> OR
>
> -a table named "document_ownership" that will have these fields : "document_id", "relation_type" and "relation_id". Here relation_type
>   field is for example a string (which represent the relation table
>   name) or a foreign key pointing to another additionnal table named for
>   example "relationtype" in which we have strings like "user" (id=1),
>   "office" (id=2), "product" (id=3) and "event" (id=4) (which also
>   represent the relation table name), and relation_id which is the id of
>   the specified relation table (relation_type)

My question is, what is the pro/cons of all these 3 ways of doing what I want and what should be the best practice please ?

Thanks in advance for your advices,

Michal

Comment: Listing pros and cons is not that difficult (enforcing data integrity through foreign keys vs flexibility of the structure), however, it is not possible to answer the best practice question, since we have absolutely no idea what the business requirements are for your project.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not really answerable as asked. A purist would say that approach 1 is correct but it is not always that simple. Think of it like this - your database design should *express* the relationships between the data and what the data means. So each of your approaches imply several things about the nature of the data.

Approach 1 says that user, office, product and event are important, and oh yeah they can have documents. Maybe.

Approach 2 says that documents are important, and we need to track what each document relates to. So the document is the key thing and everything else is annotated around that.

Approach 3 is more complicated and technical and does not really give an idea of how you want the data to be used.

In all cases the data is same. It is just designing the data to tell the story of how it should be used.

Sorry to wax lyrical. Just my $0.02.

Answer (score 0):

In a data conception (Merise) view you have :

Document-0,n---------0,n-User

Document-0,n---------0,n-Event
...

This is the logical view.

When you transform this to physical data view you will end up with 1 more table for each relation.

So the 1st solution is the way to go, if you want to apply best practice in data modelisation.

Concerning the two other solutions, which breaks some normal form :

- the second solution is a total no go. You will have a lot of null value everywhere and will strugle to do some basic statistic because of that.
- The third solution, that looks like a spaghetthi plate, will globally work and is, in my point of view, a good alternative. IF you can handle the loss of constraint integrity